yarn version 4.5.0 download is failing
I am trying to setup a repo which has
  "packageManager": "yarn@4.5.0",

in the package.json file.
when I am trying to run:
yarn -v
I get this error :
Error :
! Corepack is about to download https://repo.yarnpkg.com/4.5.0/packages/yarnpkg-cli/bin/yarn.js
? Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/corepack/dist/lib/corepack.cjs:21609
throw new Error(
I tried following this thread for solution Not able to install Yarn through corepack ,
here in the step
yarn set version stable 

I am getting this error
error This project's package.json defines "packageManager": "yarn@4.5.0". However the current global version of Yarn is 1.22.22.

That error means an invalid certificate is used when accessing repo.yarnpkg.com -- either you have a misconfigured VPN/proxy/etc., or you are being attacked.
Go to https://repo.yarnpkg.com/tags from that environment and check the certificate. At the time of writing, it should be using this certificate. If you see an invalid certificate instead, then you need to figure out why.
